# Convert .odt to .docx using libreoffice5.0 in python

Tags: apache, python-2.7, libreoffice

```
command = "libreoffice5.0  --headless --convert-to odt /data/Format/000001535edbaf8f27a9c331003600c900520045/test.docx --outdir /data/Format/000001535edbaf8f27a9c331003600c900520045"
```

When we run this command on terminal that gives me output

> /data/Format/000001535edbaf8f27a9c331003600c900520045/test.odt

But whenever I am trying with apache request `os.system(command)` it goes in process but doesn't return anything. The process keeps running in background continously.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using

```
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

> "The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes. This module intends to replace several older modules and functions:"
>
> os.system
>
> os.spawn*
>
> os.popen*
>
> popen2.*
>
> commands.*

Ref [Python 2.7.x module subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

Comment: I am not trying this , above issue raised because of permission , we can run this by applying root full permission. I got my output but if you give full permission its not good to system.